# Selecting  forests when styling google maps?

Tags: google-maps

I recently found the google maps-styling(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

I've been trying to figure out how to hide the forests. ([like the green stuff in norway](https://maps.google.com/?q=norway&ll=59.712097,13.798828&spn=13.534619,26.455078&hnear=Norway&t=m&z=5))

And change the color of all land-areas.

```
using       featureType: "landscape",
        stylers: [
          { visibility: "off" }
        ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this wizard ( http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html ) to customize the styling of your map. Then grab the JSON you created and assign it to your styling variable `var styles`. Then you can set the style variable in the map options.

The JSON that targets your question should be:

```
[
  {
    featureType: "landscape.natural",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "poi.park",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can use the wizard to change the colors of the land types as well (changing the Hue field).

Answer (score 1):

Apperntly google conciders "forests" a point of interest:

```
{
 featureType: "poi",
 stylers: [
  { visibility: "off" }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here you have style Maps Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)

At the bottom you have "More Options" click landscape -> All.

The result shows after finish click